# Clojure: Variadic function for vector addition

Tags: clojure, variadic

I want to write a general function to add vectors:

With map I can do the following:

```
(vec (map + [1 2] [1 2] [1 2]))
⇒ [3 6]

(vec (map + [1 2 3] [1 2 3] [1 2 3]))
⇒ [3 6 9]
```

I'd like be able to wrap it up into a function that takes any number of vectors. Currently I have a version that works using loop & recur:

```
(defn add-coords [& args]
  (loop [coords (first args) more (rest args)]
    (if (empty? more)
      (vec coords)
      (recur (map + coords (first more))
             (rest more)))))

(add-coords [1 2] [1 2] [1 2])
⇒ [3 6]

(add-coords [1 2 3] [1 2 3] [1 2 3])
⇒ [3 6 9]
```

Is there any way to do this in one line? Something like:

```
(defn add-coords [& args] (vec (map + args)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`apply mapv` should help:

```
user=> (defn add-coords [& args] 
         (when (seq args) 
           (apply mapv + args)))
```

in action

```
user=> (add-coords [1 2 3] [1 2 3] [1 2 3])
[3 6 9]
```